# Creating a file via FTP on Ubuntu 10.04 has default permissions of 600

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I installed VSFTP on my Ubuntu 10.04 server and haven't configured much else on it. I have an SSH user called "tom" which when I log into the FTP and try and create a file as this user, or any other for that matter, the default permissions of the file are 600 which is annoying as the web server can't read them...

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `local_umask` to the default `022` on your vsftpd.conf, alternatively you can enable suexec on your apache server which will allow you to read files with that user/groups permission without others.

Resulting in: `local_umask=022`

If you want to change the for anonymous users as well, the option directive is `anon_umask` with the same umask as above.

Comment: you welcome ;) !